# How to check Local Network Privacy permission status(Allowed or not) with NSStream TCP/IP Socket Connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

With the latest Xcode 12 and for iOS 14 Local network Permission has included as per the Suggestion in the plist. And i have been working with TCP/IP Socket connection with `NSStream` But i couldn't able find whether the user allowed or denied the local network permission, Only solution that i came to know is if the Ping fails it would through the response as `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred` which is common for wifi issue.

Is there any other way to find out that particular user permission denied?

Comment: Sadly there is no way to do this at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940427/ios-14-how-to-trigger-local-network-dialog-and-check-user-answer and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650648

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069053/how-to-detect-if-local-network-permissions-are-granted-in-ios-14/65224565#65224565