# Bonjour trouble using iOS 15, detecting "Local Network" setting

Tags: ios, bonjour, mcsession

Starting with iOS 15 (and maybe iOS 14), I had been having trouble getting Bonjour to work (it's working now).  I am using `MCSession`, `MCAdvertiserAssistant`, and `MCNearbyServiceBrowser`.  None of my delegate methods were being triggered.  It was radio silence.  (Everything worked fine with prior iOS versions.)

Eventually, I figured out that I had to turn on my app's `Local Network` switch in the device settings.  There's no documentation about this and Apple provides no easy way for an app to detect if the switch is turned off.

I found a forum posting about Bonjour, `Local Network Privacy FAQ,` written by Quinn “The Eskimo!” (Apple Developer Technical Support).  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663858.
FAQ #9, titled `How do I tell whether I’ve been granted local network access?,` offers an indirect way to learn if the Local Network switch is off.  That FAQ says:

> If you’re using Bonjour, you will get the kDNSServiceErr_PolicyDenied
> (-65570) error if your Bonjour operation failed because you don’t have
> local network access.

All of the methods I can find that return an error (e.g., MCSession's `sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:`) depend on my passing a local peer ID, but I don't have any peer IDs (other than my own) because none of my delegate methods return any information (which is how I'd learn about nearby peers).  If I don't provide a peerID, then the errors I get from that method are about not providing a valid nearby peer ID, not the `kDNSServiceErr_PolicyDenied` error that I'm looking for.

The FAQ thread is locked, so I cannot ask this question there.

**What method do I use to get the `kDNSServiceErr_PolicyDenied` error?**

I'm using Objective-C and Xcode 13.2.1.

---

FYI, my Info.Plist includes these keys: `NSBonjourServices` (array with _MyServiceType._tcp and _MyServiceType._udp), `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`, `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`, and `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription`.

Comment: Beautiful! I just needed this. There were a lot of Bonjour changes in iOS 15 …